# How do I use a Response File for installing Oracle on a different machine?

Tags: oracle, installation

I did the following:

- Installed Oracle software on Machine-1.
- Reran the Oracle Universal Installer on Machine-1 to extract only a Response File.

Now, I want to be able to use the above created Response File to install the Oracle software on Machine-2. Haven't been able to figure out yet, because there's no Oracle Universal Installer on the fresh Machine-2.

Please advice, how to go ahead with this.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to put the software/ binary there
and run the installer with response file as parameter

Please let us know the OS